# SQL Query to get last day of every week

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL, I need to query a table that has a datetime field. I need to count all the records for a particular week. Using date_format(colname, "%Y %V") returns the week #, but I need the last day (day of month 01-28|29|30|31) for that week.

Output E.g.

```
    COUNT(*) | TheDate
    11       | 2012-01-07
    22       | 2012-01-14
    123      | 2012-01-21
```

Help?

Note: Last day of the week in my case is Sunday.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the [**DAYOFWEEK**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function

If the End of the Week in Saturday, any date can be morphed into a Saturday.

For example, this computes the upcoming Saturday

```
SELECT DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(NOW())) DAY);
```

This computes the upcoming Sunday (you must use [**WEEKDAY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function instead)

```
SELECT DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(NOW())) DAY);
```

For a table called mytable with a Date Column called theDate, your summation would be

Saturday

```
SELECT COUNT(1) DateCount,EndOfWeekDate FROM
(
    SELECT DATE(theDate + INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(theDate)) DAY) EndOfWeekDate
    FROM mytable
) A GROUP BY EndOfWeekDate;
```

Sunday

```
SELECT COUNT(1) DateCount,EndOfWeekDate FROM
(
    SELECT DATE(theDate + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(theDate)) DAY) EndOfWeekDate
    FROM mytable
) A GROUP BY EndOfWeekDate;
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT if you want any other end of week other than Saturday and Sunday, [**I wrote an insane algorithm back in Sep 22, 2011 for computing any week starting and ending whatever day**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6050/877).

Answer (score 1):

Use `LAST_DAY()`.

Documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day).

Comment: This returns the last day of the *month*, not week.